# How to use docker from the machine on the gitlab docker container?

Tags: docker, gitlab, cicd

I've got a gitlab container running on docker. I want to define a gitlab runner to run the docker I use on my machine. I'm stuck.
Should I make a symlink from the container to the `docker` executable on the machine when building the image? If yes then how should I do that?
If above is not possible how should I handle the situation I have?

Comment: Note that this has nothing at all to do with Git.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct, you want an access to docker engine of your host environment from your gitlab container. So, for example, when you execute `docker ps` in your *gitlab container* you actually accessing docker engine of the host machine.

To achieve that you have to do 2 things:

- Install docker cli inside your gitlab container, I'm not familiar with this image, probably docker cli is already here, but to be sure [here](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2281) how to do this. In short:

  ```
  COPY --from=docker:latest /usr/local/bin/docker /usr/local/bin/
  ```

  This will copy cli binaries from docker image into your container.
- Docker cli communicates with docker engine via unix socket: `/var/run/docker.sock` so you'll have to mount it inside your gitlab container.

  - If your docker engine host Os is windows, you'll have to mount it
    like this:

    ```bash
    --volume //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ```
  - If your docker engine host OS is linux, it is pretty straightforward:

    ```bash
    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is docker in docker (`dind`) can be seen [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html).